# JavaScript - asking questions via cmd and storing responses to Variables. Adding this code to an already existing program

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working on a hyperledger fabric [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html). This tutorial has a Javascript application (issue.js) which:

1) Selects an identity
2)Connects to network gateway
3)Accesses PaperNet network
4) Constructs request to issue commercial paper
5) **Submit transaction**
6) Process response.

During the submit transaction, what the issue.js program does is to create an "asset record", with 6 hardcoded values that are defined within the issue.js file. I have modified the issue.js to accept 12 static values also defined in the issue.js file.

Instead of having the values hardcoded in the issue.js file, I was hoping to add a prompt via the cmd that would ask the user questions and save their responses as variables to use with the creation of these assets. Due to my limited knowledge of javascript, I have not been successful in adding the capability to ask the user a question , place the response in a variable and use it for the asset creation.

Original [issue.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/issue.js) file from hyperledger repo.

Snippet of the hardcoded section below.

```
// issue commercial paper
        console.log('Submit commercial paper issue transaction.');

        const issueResponse = await contract.submitTransaction('issue', 'MagnetoCorp', '00001', '2020-05-31', '2020-11-30', '5000000');

        // process response
        console.log('Process issue transaction response.'+issueResponse);
```

I made arraytest.js which asks three questions. The arraytest.js requires ask, ask1, and ask2 (1 for each question). (Again due to my limited JS knowledge, I copied this format from another stackoverflow response to grab input from a user.

If I run arraytest.js alone, it will ask via cmd the three questions, and capture the responses in an array, which then I simply display back out to the cmd.

I want to modify issue.js which currently creates an asset with hardcoded data, and insert my arraytest.js code to grab dynamic data for the asset creation.

[link to my files](https://github.com/dgitdos/comm-paper-edits)

issue-mod.js is issue.js modified to ask my questions, however, I get an error when I try to run it.

[issue-mod.js](https://github.com/dgitdos/comm-paper-edits/blob/master/issue-mod.js)

```
askQuestions([
                'Is it an apparel or food item?',

])
    .then(answers => {
                if(answers[0]=== "food")
                {
                        askQuestions2   ([
                                                        'What is the digital twin id?',
                                                        'What is the item? ',
                                                        'What is the Brand? ',
                                                        'What is the production date? ',
                                                        'What is the Best by date ',
                                                        'What is the Expiration date? ',
                                                        'What is the Lot Quantity? ',
                                                        'What is the Supplier? ',
                                                        'What is the farm? ',
                                                        'what is the packaged location? ',

                                                        ])
                                                        .then(answers => {

                                                                farm = answers[8]
                                                                //Just to check if the code was working. 
                                                                console.log("farm location is " + farm);



//grabbed this from the "original" issue.js and placed inside of my if statement.                                                               
main().then(() => {

    console.log('Issue program complete.');

}).catch((e) => {

    console.log('Issue program exception.');
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.stack);
    process.exit(-1);

}
```

The behavior I expect, is the cmd to ask my first question, I'll answer food and get asked the second question set. Then it will display one of the answers and then continue to execute the program as it normally would, creating the asset with its hard coded data.

However when I try to run the program, I receive the following error:

```
/home/dgitdos/Comm-Paper-Tut/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/issue.js:89
}
^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
   at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
   at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
   at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
   at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I've tried commenting out or adding different } with no success.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: The stacktrace seems pretty clear to me: _"missing ) after argument list"_. The problem is encountered in vm.js on line 80 position 10 which was called by line 139 position 10 etc etc. So you should be looking at that file / line and add the missing ")". If nothing is wrong there, you'll have to debug your script and check what's being send to that function / method

Comment: To give a very basic example, _"missing ) after argument list"_: `function foo(argument_1, argument_2 { ... }` _"correct code"_: `function foo(argument_1, argument_2) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to fix my issue by just meticulously going through my issue-mod.js file and inserting ")" and testing. My issue had nothing to do with vm.js. I tried searching for vm.js file at first, but could not find it for the life of me. That led me to realize that the error was in my issue-mod.js @icecub